# Html textbox value include ""

Tags: javascript, html

I dynamically assign a textbox value in JavaScript:

```
var html = '';
for( var s=0;  s++ ; s<10){
  html += '<input type="hidden" name="hfstepDescription'+s+'" id="hfstepDescription'+s+'" value="'+ sstepDescriptionHTML +'">';

}
```

sstepDescriptionHTML's conntent may like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="hfstepDescription11" id="hfstepDescription11" value="test1 <div class="">context1</div>">
```

But when I use `document.getElementById('hfstepDescription11').value`
I would get test1 `<div class=`, not `test1 <div class="">context1</div>`

How do I get the right value -> `test1 <div class="">context1</div>`?

Comment: Escape quotes (so that they don't interrupt attribute value context)

Comment: Why is this question a community wiki?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is encoding; if your value contains the same character enclosing the value, you basically have to encode it or to set the value otherwise.

You can choose two different paths:

First option is to escape the value before inserting it to the generated HTML:

```
var escapedValue = value.replace(/&/, "&amp;").replace(/\"/, "&quot;");

html += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"test\" id=\"test\" value=\"" + value + "\"/>";
```

Another option is to set the value after appending your HTML to the DOM:

```
document.getElementById("test").value = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're setting `sstepDescriptionHTML` but you really need to HTML encode the value of the `<input>`. The value is only going to be whatever is found between the double quotes, hence why it will only return: `test1 <div class=`

Check out [JavaScript's escape() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the double quotes with single quotes for the class attribute in div.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hfstepDescription11" id="hfstepDescription11" value="test1 <div class=''>context1</div>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I use escape() to encode textbox's value and using php code below to decode the textbox's value

then i can get the correct value

$str = uniDecode($str,'big-5');

function uniDecode($str,$charcode){
$text = preg_replace_callback("/%u[0-9A-Za-z]{4}/",toUtf8,$str);
return mb_convert_encoding($text, $charcode, 'utf-8');
}
function toUtf8($ar){
foreach($ar as $val){
$val = intval(substr($val,2),16);
if($val < 0x7F){        // 0000-007F
$c .= chr($val);
}elseif($val < 0x800) { // 0080-0800
$c .= chr(0xC0 | ($val / 64));
$c .= chr(0x80 | ($val % 64));
}else{                // 0800-FFFF
$c .= chr(0xE0 | (($val / 64) / 64));
$c .= chr(0x80 | (($val / 64) % 64));
$c .= chr(0x80 | ($val % 64));
}
}
return $c;
}

Answer (score 0):

I use escape() to encode textbox's value and using php code - http://www.neo.com.tw/archives/000152   - to decode the textbox's value

then i can get the correct value

Answer (score 0):

You can escape it using the method described in the following post

http://hemanshubhojak.com/Home/Post?postId=7